# Is it possible to move from a German language study visa to a 90-day tourist visa?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, schengen-visas, customs-and-immigration

I will try to keep this short and sweet. I have obtained a German language learning visa in Germany. It expires on September 1st, 2018 (I applied for it in October, so it is an 1-month visa, just in case this information helps). I would like to find a way to stay and do some traveling after my classes end in August since I really haven't had a chance to explore.

I have been reading online that you can deregister the class D visa, fly to the UK and re-enter into France to start a 90-day tourist visa (granted to us Americans by our passport). But I don't know how accurate this information is and I don't want to chance being deported in September if this is not the case. Anyone have experience with this? Or know where I might be able to go to get an accurate answer?

TL;DR Trying to move from study visa to tourist visa by going to the UK and re-entering a Schengen country. Will this work?

Comment: Americans can make short visits to the Schengen area **without a visa**. There is no such thing as "90-day tourist visa granted to Americans". On the contrary, US citizens _cannot get a short stay Schengen visa_, because such a thing would not allow them to do anything they can't already do visa-free.

Comment: I understand that I don’t need a short stay Visa as an american, I am just trying to figure out that if I leave to the UK on say August 28th, my residence visa to Germany ends on September 1st, that I’d  be able to re-enter into France on the second of September on just my passport alone. Because when I came in last September 2017 I got an entrance stamp into Germany, then in October 2017 I received my residence visa for studying. I just need to be sure that I won’t be denied re-entry on my passport only because my flights are booked to return to USA from Amsterdam end of October.